# Eclipse on Ubuntu karmic hangs when using subclipse to connect to HTTPS repository

Tags: svn, eclipse, https, subclipse, gnome-keyring

Software versions in use:

- Eclipse Galileo

  - SVN Team Core Provider 1.6.5
  - Subversion client adapter 1.6.4.1
  - Subversion JavaHL 1.6.5
- svn, version 1.6.5 (r38866)
- Ubuntu karmic

When I select *Checkout from SVN* I select the HTTPS repository, but it stays at *Pending...* forever. When I remove any information from `~/.subversion` I get asked for the self-signed certificate, accept it permanently and also check to store my credentials.

I can close the dialog, but Eclipse won't respond anymore and I need to `kill` it.

I used [jconsole](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) to inspect what's going on and found one of the worker threads with this stack trace:

```
Name: Worker-0
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 78  Total waited: 183

Stack trace: 
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.list(Native Method)
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.list(SVNClient.java:201)
org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getList(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:349)
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.RemoteFolder.getMembers(RemoteFolder.java:164)
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.RemoteFolder.members(RemoteFolder.java:256)
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.FetchMembersOperation.execute(FetchMembersOperation.java:41)
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.SVNOperation.run(SVNOperation.java:89)
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.repository.model.SVNRepositoryRootElement.fetchDeferredChildren(SVNRepositoryRootElement.java:73)
org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:234)
org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Only when I **not** accept my self-signed certificate permanently (I get asked to accept the certificate every time e.g. when I open a node to select for checkout) it "works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaHL FAQ](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-3a1d2d3c54791d2d751794e5d6645f1d77d95b32) :

> There is currently a bug in the new support for GNOME keyring in Subversion 1.6. It works OK when using the command line, but not when other users of the libraries use it. Until this is fixed, you can workaround the problem by turning off this feature.

The solution is to put the line

```
password-stores =
```

in `~/.subversion/config`, effectively disabling the keyring.

This was from an answer from the [subclipse mailing list](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=2397451).